# I want execution of the program to ask for the values of a matrix

Tags: python

I'm a beginner. I might not word this exactly right. I want the execution of the program to ask for the values of a matrix.

I will try to create a similar code to produce another matrix within the same code in order to perform operations on both matrices.

Below is what I really want help with in order to help achieve my main goal above:

- I want the user to input their dimensions.
- I want the user to tell the values of the matrix in the execution part of the program.
- I want the program to print the matrix.

I tried Python all day but only got lists to work.

Code from another site:

```
row1 = []
n = int(input("Enter the list size "))
print("\n")
for i in range(0, n):
    print("Enter number at index", [i])
    item = int(input())
    row1.append(item)
print("User list is ", row1)
```

I also tried:

```
rownk = []
n = int(input("Enter the list size for rows: "))
k = int(input("Enter the list size for columns: "))
print("\n")
for i in range(0, n):
    for j in range(0, k):
        print("Enter number at row", i, "column", j)
        item = int(input())
        rownk.append(item)
print("Matrix is: ", rownk)
```

I thought it should be a loop inside of a loop.

This isn't homework. I'm just trying to learn to program on my own and I have a little thing for math.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: @randomgirl I have edited your post, please review to see if I got it right.

Comment: "Users enter the size of a matrix (as separate values for the number of rows and columns), the code creates an empty list called rownk, and then uses nested for loops to ask users to enter a number at each row/column position of the matrix. The following loop appends each entered number to the rownk list. The code prints the rownk list to show users the complete matrix they entered." - what do you try to achieve?

Comment: You could provide some sample inputs and expected outputs (if the program is working) - that will be much clear.

Comment: @DanielHao Good point. Inputs and expected outputs would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're very close to the solution,  if I understand your req. clearly, you just need to do *append* to create the *sublist* in each loop.  Try this:

Note - there are many other ways to create this type of *matrix* - eg. List Comprehension more concisely.  Also try to choose a more descriptive and meaningful variables could be helpful for the *future self* *down the road.*

```py
# get dimensions from user
row = int(input("Enter the number of rows: "))
col = int(input("Enter the number of columns: "))

# create an empty matrix
matrix = []

# get values for each element 
for r in range(row):
    rows = []
    
    for c in range(col):
        item = int(input("Enter number at row {} column {}: ".format(r, c)))
        rows.append(item)      # <---- put in each row's to make a sublist now
        
    matrix.append(rows)

# print the matrix
print("Matrix is:")

for items in matrix:
    print(items)       # each row's items
```

#### In Actions:

```
Enter the number of rows: 3
Enter the number of columns: 3
Enter number at row 0 column 0: 1
Enter number at row 0 column 1: 2
Enter number at row 0 column 2: 3
Enter number at row 1 column 0: 4
Enter number at row 1 column 1: 5
Enter number at row 1 column 2: 6
Enter number at row 2 column 0: 7
Enter number at row 2 column 1: 8
Enter number at row 2 column 2: 9
Matrix is:
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Wow. This looks fantastic. I can't wait to get to my main computer and try it. Thanks so much.

Comment: Thank you so very much. I had to turn off this program idea for a week or two. After I came back to it, your code made so much more sense to me that I was able to complete my matrix multiplication program. You are so awesome. Thank you again so so very much. This is my 3rd working program I have made in my life. I'm at the very beginning of learning. I love mixing what I learn in maths into programming.